# many apache mail logged in maillog every minute

Tags: apache, redhat, postfix-mta

Server: Apache 2.4 Red Hat 
Is it necessary to log the below records in every minute? Or do I have a wrong setting in my server?

> Nov  2 11:01:02 xxx postfix/pickup[13256]: 1BC2C1BCC36: uid=48 from=
>
> Nov  2 11:01:02 xxx postfix/cleanup[12959]: 1BC2C1BCC36: message-id=<20171102030102.1BC2C1BCC36@xxx.com>
>
> Nov  2 11:01:02 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: 1BC2C1BCC36: from=, size=1166, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Nov  2 11:01:02 xxx postfix/local[13277]: 1BC2C1BCC36: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.03/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
>
> Nov  2 11:01:02 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: 1BC2C1BCC36: removed
>
> Nov  2 11:01:02 xxx postfix/pickup[13256]: A5C521BCC36: uid=48 from=
>
> Nov  2 11:01:02 xxx postfix/cleanup[12959]: A5C521BCC36: message-id=<20171102030102.A5C521BCC36@xxx.com>
>
> Nov  2 11:01:02 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: A5C521BCC36: from=, size=797, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Nov  2 11:01:02 xxx postfix/local[13279]: A5C521BCC36: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=0.67, delays=0.66/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
>
> Nov  2 11:01:02 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: A5C521BCC36: removed
>
> Nov  2 11:01:03 xxx postfix/pickup[13256]: AB8321BCC36: uid=48 from=
>
> Nov  2 11:01:03 xxx postfix/cleanup[12959]: AB8321BCC36: message-id=<20171102030103.AB8321BCC36@xxx.com>
>
> Nov  2 11:01:03 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: AB8321BCC36: from=, size=881, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Nov  2 11:01:03 xxx postfix/local[13277]: AB8321BCC36: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=1.6, delays=1.6/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
>
> Nov  2 11:01:03 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: AB8321BCC36: removed
>
> Nov  2 11:02:01 xxx postfix/pickup[13256]: D8E7F1BCC3E: uid=48 from=
>
> Nov  2 11:02:01 xxx postfix/cleanup[12959]: D8E7F1BCC3E: message-id=<20171102030201.D8E7F1BCC3E@xxx.com>
>
> Nov  2 11:02:01 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: D8E7F1BCC3E: from=, size=1166, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Nov  2 11:02:01 xxx postfix/local[13279]: D8E7F1BCC3E: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.05/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
>
> Nov  2 11:02:01 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: D8E7F1BCC3E: removed
>
> Nov  2 11:02:02 xxx postfix/pickup[13256]: 71BDF1BCC3E: uid=48 from=
>
> Nov  2 11:02:02 xxx postfix/cleanup[13717]: 71BDF1BCC3E: message-id=<20171102030202.71BDF1BCC3E@xxx.com>
>
> Nov  2 11:02:02 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: 71BDF1BCC3E: from=, size=797, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Nov  2 11:02:02 xxx postfix/local[13277]: 71BDF1BCC3E: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=0.67, delays=0.66/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
>
> Nov  2 11:02:02 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: 71BDF1BCC3E: removed
>
> Nov  2 11:02:03 xxx postfix/pickup[13256]: 686271BCC3E: uid=48 from=
>
> Nov  2 11:02:03 xxx postfix/cleanup[13717]: 686271BCC3E: message-id=<20171102030203.686271BCC3E@xxx.com>
>
> Nov  2 11:02:03 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: 686271BCC3E: from=, size=881, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Nov  2 11:02:03 xxx postfix/local[13279]: 686271BCC3E: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=1.6, delays=1.6/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
>
> Nov  2 11:02:03 xxx postfix/qmgr[1983]: 686271BCC3E: removed